# Drawing coordinates with opengl

Tags: opengl, 3d, drawing, coordinate-systems

I just want to draw a 3D graph in openGL.

Technically I have readings from a sensor and from each point of the sensor I want to show the height of the reading.

My data looks like this

```
368,57,0.347924,
367,606,0.333651
```

the values being row,column and height of my reading.

This is the code I have so far basically just manupulated some found codes in the internet.

```
void on_opengl(void* param)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPointSize(3);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ )
    {
        glVertex3fv(&my_data[i*3]);
    }
    glEnd();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namedWindow("3d",CV_WINDOW_OPENGL|CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    setOpenGlDrawCallback("3d",on_opengl,0);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

here my_data is the coordinates an heights. But I get nothing in the picture.

Also if you think there is a better choice than openGL let me know I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: what xactly do you mean by 3D here ?

Comment: xyz chart. just to show the data i have in xyz manner

Comment: Ok then may be OpenGl is the right choice but you will have to do a little more reading then this..!!

Comment: OR may be you want to use something little more highlevel like this http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/web/navigation/feature_frame.html

Comment: @AbhishekBansal No I don't need high level, But can you help a bit like what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you have to set the camera, opengl only renders points between (-1,-1) and (1,1) by default

Comment: There is no camera! I have data to present in 3D. I tried to make all the numbers less than 1 and still no resutl

Comment: see thats why i said that you need a little more reading about how OpenGL works..!! You need to setup Camera and Projection for starters... There are default settings you should lookup internet for that

Comment: You have to normalize the coordinates to [-1,1] first and foremost since you have no projection/modelview matrix setup. That coordinate space maps (-1,-1,-1) to the bottom-left corner of your viewport and (1,1,-1) to the top-right. Without perspective, the only difference the Z coordinate will make is depth testing (assuming it is in the range [-1,1]). But then you have to realize that `GL_QUADS` requires 4 vertices. You want `GL_POINTS`.